# Можно ли сменить тему maps google

Tags: java, android, activity, google-maps, android-themes

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста можно ли изменить тему map google
Есть на фрагменте карта

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>
```

Вопрос: есть ли возможность изменить именно тему карты, например для ночи, чтобы все что изображено на карте было в более темных тонах.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, с недавних пор это возможно. Вот дока: [Adding a Styled Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling)

Кратко:

1. Стиль задаётся в JSON формате.
2. Надо поместить файл со стилем в `/res/raw/style_json`
3. выглядеть должно так-то так:

   ```
   [
     {
       "featureType": "all",
       "elementType": "geometry",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#242f3e"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "all",
       "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "lightness": -80
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "administrative",
       "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#746855"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "administrative.locality",
       "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#d59563"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "poi",
       "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#d59563"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "poi.park",
       "elementType": "geometry",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#263c3f"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "poi.park",
       "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#6b9a76"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "road",
       "elementType": "geometry.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#2b3544"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "road",
       "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#9ca5b3"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "road.arterial",
       "elementType": "geometry.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#38414e"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "road.arterial",
       "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#212a37"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "road.highway",
       "elementType": "geometry.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#746855"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "road.highway",
       "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#1f2835"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "road.highway",
       "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#f3d19c"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "road.local",
       "elementType": "geometry.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#38414e"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "road.local",
       "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#212a37"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "transit",
       "elementType": "geometry",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#2f3948"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "transit.station",
       "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#d59563"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "water",
       "elementType": "geometry",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#17263c"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "water",
       "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "color": "#515c6d"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "featureType": "water",
       "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
       "stylers": [
         {
           "lightness": -20
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
   ```
4. Далее, в колбэке успешной загрузки карты вам надо загрузить стиль в карту. Вот код активити с картой и загрзкой стиля в колбэке из доки:

   ```
   import android.content.res.Resources;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.util.Log;

   import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
   import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;

   /**
    * A styled map using JSON styles from a raw resource.
    */
   public class MapsActivityRaw extends AppCompatActivity
           implements OnMapReadyCallback {

       private static final String TAG = MapsActivityRaw.class.getSimpleName();

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_raw);

           // Get the SupportMapFragment and register for the callback
           // when the map is ready for use.
           SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                   (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                           .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
           mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
       }

       /**
        * Manipulates the map when it's available.
        * The API invokes this callback when the map is ready for use.
        */
       @Override
       public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

           try {
               // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
               // in a raw resource file.
               boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                       MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                               this, R.raw.style_json));

               if (!success) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
               }
           } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
           }
           // Position the map's camera near Sydney, Australia.
           googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(-34, 151)));
       }
   }
   ```

---

Там же, в доке, есть подробности о составлении стиля и несколько примеров стилей